# Remove a css property using angular or javascript

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, event-handling

I have a div class `<div class="filter-wrapper filter-name-of-hotel ">` and the css for that class is this.

```
.filter-name-of-hotel:after {
    content: '\f002';
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 10px;
    color: black;
    font-size: 23px;
}
```

in the the div class there's a textbox element. When I click on that textbox I want to remove 'content' property from the class. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Use 2 classes:

```
.filter-name-of-hotel.withContent:after {
    content: '\f002'; 
}
.filter-name-of-hotel:after {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome'; 
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 0px; 
    right: 10px; 
    color: black;
    font-size: 23px; 
}
```

now just remove the class `withContent` when clicking inside the textbox

```
$('#div').removeClass('withContent');
```

Comment: Also the div class has more than once class.

<div class="filter-wrapper filter-name-of-hotel ">

Answer (score 0):

I don't know to remove content in class. But i think, you can define other class the same current class but without content. After, use JS check when click text will replace class name.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using just css. Make a css rule for your text area.

```
textarea{
   background-color:blue;
}
```

and then make a css rule for when the textarea is focused

```
textarea:focus{
   background-color: red;
}
```

This will set the textarea to red when selected and blue when no selected.

This is also possible using ng-class, you should check it out:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Also here is a code pen showing how to do it an Angular way:

Updated my code pen. This shows how to solve your problem:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dodZZx

Comment: I need the answer regarding my question. I only want to remove the property what I mentioned.